# Joining tables not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to convert my db query to **codeigniter active records** but can not seem to work it out properly the correct way.

**What am I doing wrong.**

```
Error
Error Number: 1066
Not unique table/alias: 'user_group'
SELECT * FROM (`user_group`, `user`) JOIN `user_group` ON WHERE `ug`.`user_group_id` IS NULL AND `u`.`user_id` = '1'
Filename: C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-project\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Model

```
public function getUser($user_id) {
   $this->db->select('*', 'ug.user_group', 'u.user');
   $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group');
   $this->db->join('user_group');
   $this->db->where('ug.user_group_id');
   $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
   $this->db->where('u.user_id', $user_id);
   $query = $this->db->get();

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->result_array();
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
 }
```

Old Model Way

```
public function getUser1($user_id) {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, (SELECT ug.name FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group` ug WHERE 
   ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id) 
   AS user_group FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . 
   "user` u WHERE u.user_id = '" . (int)$user_id . "'");

  return $query->row_array();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have passed wrong syntax for join. Please try with below code

```
$this->db->select('user.*,user_group.name as user_group');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->join('user_group','user.user_group_id = user_group.user_group_id');
$this->db->where('user.user_id', $user_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Let me know if still you are having any error/issue with this query.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried that but now Unknown column 'user_group_id.user_group_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Is your old model way query was working? If yes, can you please confirm that user_group_id is available in both user and user_group table. Or can you please let me know the column names from both the tables on which you want to make join.

Comment: Yea was working I don't want to manually enter the column names on model user group column name user_group_id, name, permission

Comment: I have edited answer, can you please try now with updated code.

Comment: Nothing worked. Looks like will have to stick with the db query

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the below..
Answer from "PHP Weblineindia" is pretty much the same, but they missed the db prefixes.

```
$this->db->select('u.*, ug.name AS user_group');
$this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user u');
$this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group ug', 'ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id');
$this->db->where('u.user_id', $user_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Untested code, just based on what I can see from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please user this code

```
 public function getUser($user_id) {

 $this->db->select(array('*', 'ug.user_group', 'u.user'));     
 $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix .'user_group AS ug','ug.column = u.column','INNER');
 //please user column similar in both tables
 $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user as u');
 $this->db->where('u.user_id', $user_id);
 $query = $this->db->get();

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result_array();
    return true;
   } else {
  return false;
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.